# Mac os x app bundle crashes when downloaded and run, but runs fine in the terminal or when changing Info.plist

Tags: c++, macos, qt, cocoa, cmake

Building and running a Mac OS X application bundle works fine. Even copying the .dmg image to another mac using rsync and running on this 'virgin' MacBook works fine. Uploading the .dmg to a website, downloading it and trying to run the program, activates a security measure warning the user that

> the application can’t be opened because the identity of the developer cannot be confirmed. Your security preferences allow installation of only apps from the App Store and identified developers.
>   “TestApp” is on the disk image “TestApp.dmg”. Firefox downloaded this
>   disk image today at 10:16 from somewebsite.com

So far this is normal behaviour, but when trying to open the app using the security and privacy tab in system preferences, it displays the same message after which the program immediately crashes. 
Excerpt from the crash dump:

```
Exception Type:        EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
Exception Codes:       KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x0000000000000000
Exception Note:        EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY

Termination Signal:    Segmentation fault: 11
Termination Reason:    Namespace SIGNAL, Code 0xb
Terminating Process:   exc handler [0]

VM Regions Near 0:
--> 
    __TEXT                 0000000106e23000-00000001072a7000 [ 4624K] r-x/rwx SM=COW  bV [/var/folders/9c/_5lswjs174q6xxbf9qs6gqcc0000gn/T/AppTranslocation/659F14AE-09F4-4A1A-84A8-DA6BE86F6F4E/d/TestApp.app/Contents/MacOS/TestApp]

Thread 0 Crashed:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
0   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff6ddd5232 strlen + 18
1   Test.app                        0x0000000106e52a45 std::__1::char_traits<char>::length(char const*) + 21
2   Test.app                        0x0000000106e39d5c std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >& std::__1::operator<<<std::__1::char_traits<char> >(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&, char const*) + 44
3   Test.app                        0x0000000106e7ae04 main + 1492
4   libdyld.dylib                   0x00007fff6dd85015 start + 1
```

Running the executable inside the downloaded app bundle directly in the terminal works fine though. 
When I change the value of the `CFBundleExecutable` key in the `TestApp.app/Contents/Info.plist` file, it surprisingly works fine.

This makes me believe something is wrong with codesigning, though I'm not familiar at all with developing on Mac OS X.

Inspecting the downloaded but not altered application bundle using `codesign -dvvvv testApp.app` gives the following result `Info.plist entries=20`. After altering Info.plist the same line says `Info.plist=not bound`

More background:
I wanted to avoid using xcode, as the same building procedure should be used on Windows and Linux. 
I've built a C++ program using CMAKE and created an app bundle like so:

```
add_executable( TestApp MACOSX_BUNDLE ${SOURCES} ${MOC_SRCS} )
target_link_libraries( TestApp ${LIBRARIES} ) 
set_target_properties(TestApp PROPERTIES MACOSX_BUNDLE_BUNDLE_NAME "TestApp")
```

It depends on some external libraries like QT, OpenCV, boost, which the executable dynamically links to. I copied all necessary dylib files into the TestApp.app/Contents/Frameworks directory and altered the paths in the executable and libraries using 'otool' and 'install_name_tool'. The following manually created Info.plist file is then copied to TestApp.app/Content/Info.plist.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>BuildMachineOSBuild</key>
    <string>17D102</string>
    <key>CFBundleDevelopmentRegion</key>
    <string>en</string>
    <key>CFBundleExecutable</key>
    <string>TestApp</string>
    <key>CFBundleIdentifier</key>
    <string>abc.testapp</string>
    <key>CFBundleInfoDictionaryVersion</key>
    <string>4.0</string>
    <key>CFBundleName</key>
    <string>TestApp</string>
    <key>CFBundlePackageType</key>
    <string>APPL</string>
    <key>CFBundleShortVersionString</key>
    <string>1.0</string>
    <key>CFBundleSupportedPlatforms</key>
    <array>
        <string>MacOSX</string>
    </array>
    <key>CFBundleVersion</key>
    <string>1</string>
    <key>DTCompiler</key>
    <string>com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0</string>
    <key>DTPlatformBuild</key>
    <string>9F2000</string>
    <key>DTPlatformVersion</key>
    <string>GM</string>
    <key>DTSDKBuild</key>
    <string>17E189</string>
    <key>DTSDKName</key>
    <string>macosx10.13</string>
    <key>DTXcode</key>
    <string>0941</string>
    <key>DTXcodeBuild</key>
    <string>9F2000</string>
    <key>LSMinimumSystemVersion</key>
    <string>10.13</string>
    <key>NSMainNibFile</key>
    <string>MainMenu</string>
    <key>NSPrincipalClass</key>
    <string>NSApplication</string>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Then I use '/local/Qt/5.10.1/clang_64/bin/macdeployqt TestApp.app -codesign="Mac Developer: my@account.com (123456)" -dmg -verbose=3' to copy QT's files into the bundle, change the run paths, codesign all libraries and the bundle itself and create a dmg.
Running this program works on the macbook on which it is developed, it works on other macs when the dmg is transferred using rsync. It doesn't work when uploading to and downloading from a website. Surprisingly, adapting the Info.plist file of the downloaded app bundle or running the executable directly in the terminal works though.

Comment: In order to help you debug your code we need to see your code. At a guess based on the stack trace something in main is printing a `const char *` string but the pointer is null. we need a [mcve]

Comment: Based only on the stack trace, that would indeed be a good guess, however, in quite some scenarios (see above), the program runs fine. Not using my manually created Info.plist, but using the one generated by macdeployqt solved the weird issue.

Answer (score 1):

Not using my manually created Info.plist, but using the one generated by macdeployqt solved the issue. Still not quite satisfied, as I don't get why using a wrong Info.plist would trigger a segfault, but at least it's solved.

Comment: Did you ever find out more about this? I'm having the same issue right now.